# Native rsync library?

Tags: shared-libraries, rsync

Do there exist any good rsync libraries that implement:

1. The rsync algorithm and
2. The rsync protocol

Such that one could use the library to build the `rsync` tool itself?  (I want my application to be compatible with a normal rsync server or normal rsync over ssh.)

Comment: There is one (an unofficial reimplementation): https://github.com/gilbertchen/acrosync-library

Answer (score 1):

For rsync algorithm :-
rsync uses zlib as part of it's source code .Inside it is adler-32 algorithm and inflate and deflate algorithms (compression - decompression )implemented.

Also do check this, haven't used it myself :-
http://librsync.sourceforge.net/

for rsync protocol :-

But, I highly doubt there is library for rsync protocol(means there is no library for rsync protocol).

Comment: "But, I highly doubt there is library for rsync protocol." some research has suggested the rsync protocol isn't even documented or particularly stable, which is baffling.